# Provisioning Profile Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

My Apple Certificate had expired. So i went in the Developer's Provisioning Area and `Revoked` My certificate. I deleted my old certificate, and old provisioning profiles. 
Upon notification from my Team Lead. I downloaded the new Developer Certificate to my Mac and Dragged it into `KeyChain Access`. Now it shows my certificate as `valid`. I re-downloaded the provisioning profile for my App. and Dragged it into XCode4. The Organizer shows it to be valid but with a warning

`XCode Could not find a valid private key/certificate pair for this profile in the keychain.`

Have i done something wrong in my approach.

I am able to run my app on the iPAD and debug it too. But i somehow sense an issue in the above statement.

Please Help.

Comment: Might you need to request a new certificate using Keychain? The old key wouldn't match the new certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't recreate the provisioning profile with the new developer certificate (i.e. if you downloaded the old profile) then I think this is the problem - you will need to create a new profile with your new certificate.

Comment: I requested my Team Lead to create a new Provisioning Profile like the new Certificate which he had given me earlier. 
On Downloading the Profile the warning sign has gone from the Organizer. Although i dont get an Active or any such Message, Status message is blank, I hope this is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

You did to get the certificate key/pair from your team leader. Apple does this weird thing where it actually signs it's certificate with a "password" in order to use the certificate you have to have the "password". That's why you get XCode Could not find a valid private key/certificate pair for this profile in the keychain. I had the same thing, you can't just download the new certificate :(. If I can find the documentation of Apple that says how to do this I will post it in an edit.

Ok here is the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2

It is under "Provisioning a Device for Development", I Hope this helps!